# Automate the generation of FDF files

Tags: excel, vba, comments, fdf

I am looking to transfer comments from PDF files, via FDF files, into Excel. I am wondering whether it is feasible to automate the generation of the FDF files by some VBA code. I've not tried writing any code yet but had hoped to get a feel for whether I am at least asking a reasonable question. 
Cheers, Dave

Comment: You can use the free Adobe FDF Toolkit for Windows. It's old but it still works.
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html

Comment: That's fantastic @joelgeraci. Thanks for the suggestion. Dave.